# PNP high-side switching with logic reverse

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt, industrial, high-side

I am trying to design a High side switch(24V,10A) using a PNP Transistor, the switch control signal is PNP or NPN from the PLC output.

How to select the control signal type (NPN or PNP) using a selectable switch?

Comment: "*... the switch control signal is PNP or NPN from the PLC output.*" It's got to be one or the other. Which is it? Or are you asking how to make it **switch** selectable? "*How to select the control signal type (NPN or PNP) using a button?*" You probably mean a switch. A button will change state when you release it. Does it matter if the output is inverted logic (something that is fixable in the PLC code)?

Comment: @Transistor , Sorry, I edited the question, it should be selectable using a switch.

Comment: All transistor types invert as switches !  Mind the power dissipation.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fceyGG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Here's the general idea using a MOSFET.*

- For PNP output Q1 is held **on** by R1. Q1 will turn off when Q2 (the PLC output) turns on.
- For NPN output Q3 is held **off** by R4. Q3 will turn on when Q4 (the PLC output) turns on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWKCN4.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. With the addition of an external opto-isolator both PNP and NPN modes become non-inverting.*

The application seems a bit daft as with a second pole on the switch the load could be switched to operate as shown in Figure 3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFAvJU.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. No-nonsense solution using DPDT switch.*

Comment: Might be helpful to the OP to show how a DPDT switch could invert the logic for you so you wouldn't have to modify the PLC code for the two cases.

Comment: Go ahead, @ErikR. I think I've done enough.

Comment: Thank very much, the application is to switch high current loads using PLC. I will try it.

Comment: Why aren't you using a relay or SSR?

Comment: @Transistor Because the relay and SSR are expensive.